# Проблема с register_message_handler Python.aiogram не понимаю как добавить фильтр

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
#@dp.message_handler(commands=['setup'])
async def setup_command (message: types.Message):
    await messages_to_send.order_button()

#@dp.message_handler(FSM_user.username, Text(equals="Давай"))
async def setup_username_checker (message:types.Message , state:FSMContext):
    await messages_to_send.welcome_message()

def registr_handlers(dp:Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler (setup_command, commands=['setup'])
    dp.register_message_handler (setup_username_checker,(Text(equals="Давай")),  state=FSM_user.username)
```

есть такой код, по кнопке SETUP появляется выбор ["Давай" и "второй выбор"]. Не понимаю почему при нажатии на "Давай" не исполняется продолжение кода а откликается обработчик мусора. Как сделать фильтр и зарегистрировать его через Registr

Обработчик мусора стоит после регистратора

```
main_scenario.registr_handlers(dp)


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_answers( message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(text="Честно скажу, я не понял чего ты хочешь.")
```

[image: Клавиатура]

[image: То что он выдает]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все ответ нашел. Я дуралей не поставил хэндлер в ожидание состояния